# Wrong default mail view directory?

Tags: craft3, emails

I have a throuble with email sending from Craft CMS 3.

For example, I'm trying to send email based on a custom view placed in mail/test.php. So I wrote this code:

```
    \Craft::$app->mailer
        ->compose('test', [])
        ->setTo('test@domain.local')
        ->setSubject('Test message')
        ->send();
```

In runtime I've got an error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\ViewNotFoundException' with message 'The view file does not exist: /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/mail/test.php'

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:233

Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('/app/vendor/cra...', Array, Object(craft\mail\Mailer))
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mail/BaseMailer.php(302): yii\base\View->render('test', Array, Object(craft\mail\Mailer))
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/mail/BaseMailer.php(194): yii\mail\BaseMailer->render('test', Array, 'layouts/html')
#3 /app/modules/subscription/commands/TestController.php(149): yii\mail\BaseMailer->compose('test', Array)
#4 [internal function]: modules\subscription\commands\TestController->actionTest4()
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(184): yii\base\Controller->runAction('test4', Array)
#8 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Controller.php(192): yii\console\Controller->runAction('test4', Array)
#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): craft\console\Controller->runAction('test4', Array)
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction('subscription/te...', Array)
#11 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(89): yii\console\Application->runAction('subscription/te...', Array)
#12 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): craft\console\Application->runAction('subscription/te...', Array)
#13 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\console\Request))
#14 /app/craft(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

I suppose Craft looks for my view in a wrong place. There are no view in the vendor dir. After that I added some config into config/app.php to fix this issue:

```
    'components' => [
        // ............
        'mailer' => function () {
            $config = craft\helpers\App::mailerConfig();
            $config['viewPath'] = '@root/mail'; // here we tell to Craft where our email views are
            return Craft::createObject($config);
        },
        // ............
    ],
```

And the letter was successfully sent. It seems like Craft CMS has broken mailer out of the box. Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly in what context you're sending your email (i.e., whether it's in response to some event on the front/back end), but here's an example of how I'd send an email in a plugin or module. Key here is that in order to access your Craft `templates` directory, you need to switch the template mode from CP to SITE. You can then use `setHtmlBody` and `renderTemplate` to parse your template as the email's body. The `renderTemplate` method allows you to pass some variables to the template too like this:

```php
// need to switch template mode to use 'SITE' (as opposed to CP).
$oldMode = Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);

$mailer = Craft::$app->getMailer();
$mailer->compose()
    ->setTo($this->email)
    ->setSubject('Product information from Acme Corp')
    ->setHtmlBody(
        Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('emails/productEmail.twig', [
            'productId' => $this->productId,
            'siteHandle' => $this->siteHandle,
            'productImg' => $this->productImg,
            'videoThumb' => $this->videoThumb,
        ])
    )
    ->send();

// put the template mode back again in case more code needs to execute...
Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);
```